# probability of 3 different experiments

Tags: probability

If I have 3 different experiements **E**, and a succes **S**, and probability of S for E1 is 50 %, probability of S for E2 is 30 %, and probability of S for E3 is 30 %... is it possible to do each experiment ONCE and then calculate the possibility of AT LEAST one success, and if so, how?

I mean, at least one success OVERAll, not one for each experiment.

Comment: The easiest way to calculate the "probability of at least one" of anything is often to first calculate the "probability of none", and go from there.

Comment: We will need to assume independence.

Answer (score 1):

The probability that you have no successes is:
$$
0.5 \cdot 0.7 \cdot 0.7 = \frac{49}{200}
$$ 
Therefore the probability of at least one success is 
$
1 - \frac{49}{200} = \boxed{\frac{151}{200}}
$

Note that this assumes independence.

Answer (score 0):

**P(0)**=0.5*0.7*0.7 = 0.245 (all fail)

**P(>1)** = 1 - **P(0)** = 1 - 0.245 = **0.755**